# Where should I place XSD files/content in a SSIS project

Tags: ssis, xsd

I have an XML Source task which requires a XSD to generate my data flow work from my XML files in SSIS.   How can I embed the XSD file within the SLN/DTSX project and have it be referenced correctly?   It would seem the best case would be to have the XSD source inside a variable, but I dont see where I can do that given the XML Source data task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Project Deployment model it is possible to get the miscellaneous files bundled with the deployment.  However I want to use the Project Deployment model.  That model does not allow for files other than the ispac file.   To get around the problem using this following post as reference [SSIS dynamic xsd source file](http://fuzzy-group.blogspot.com/2013/01/ssis-create-dynamic-xsd-source-file-for.html)

Effectively you store the XSD within a available sql server database as a XML schema, use a dataflow to query for it, and store it in a RAW FILE.  Then save the RAW file to disk for future use.  Very Effective